# How to use tput to overwrite a line printed by read

Tags: bash, shell, sh

The `tput cuu 1 && tput el` works very well in case of multiple `echo`. But, how to replace a line printed by a `read`?

```
echo "First line..."
read -p "Press any key to overwrite this line... " -n1 -s
tput cuu 1 && tput el
echo "Second line. read replaced."
```

The example above outputs:

`First line...                   Second line. read replaced.`

I'd like the final results to be:

`First line...
Second line. read replaced.`

Comment: `tput cuu1` moves the cursor up by 1 but the row is left intact. You need to move cursor to the left as well.

Comment: @alvits isn't `tput el` basically supposed to wipe out the entire line?

Comment: No. `el` is erase end of line from the current position.

Comment: You might want to use this as a reference http://tldp.org/HOWTO/Bash-Prompt-HOWTO/x405.html

Comment: The best is to save the cursor position before reading: `tput sc`. Then read. Now restore the cursor position and clear end of line: `tput rc; tput el`. Finally print the second line.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code is not moving the cursor to column 0.

A simple solution is to save the cursor position before letting `read` print the prompt using`tput sc`.

After reading the user input you can restore cursor position with `tput rc`.

Your code should now look line this.

```
echo "First line..."
tput sc
read -p "Press any key to overwrite this line... " -n1 -s
tput rc 1; tput el
echo "Second line. read replaced."
```

Hope this helps.